# C# remove recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to rewrite recursive programs as iterative for practice. I have the following code to return all permutations of a string. I have been trying to convert the following recursive program into an iterative program but seems like I am stuck. The challenge here is that I am not able to convert it into Tail recursion which can then be converted into a loop. Any ideas ?

```
class clsPermutations
{
    private string str = "";
    private bool[] used;
    private StringBuilder sOut = new StringBuilder();
    public clsPermutations(string inString)
    {
        str = inString;
        used = new bool[str.Length];
    }

    public void returnPermutations()
    {
        if (sOut.Length == str.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sOut);
            return;
        }

        for (int i =0; i< str.Length;i++)
        {
            if (used[i])
                continue;
            sOut.Append(str.Substring(i, 1));
            // string sTest = str.Substring(i, 1);
            used[i] = true;
            returnPermutations();
            used[i] = false;
            sOut.Remove(sOut.Length-1,1);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your current implementation will potentially create duplicate entries; if I pass in the string "catty", it will give me two entries for "ttcay" (for one example). Is this wanted, or a bug?

Comment: For this discussion, lets assume that the string has no repeating chars. I just want to see if we can solve this without recursion, I am trying to use Stack